# How to efficiently collect all (string) values for all attributes of an LDAP search in a `char*[]` using the OpenLDAP 2.6 C client library?

Tags: c, openldap

I am implementing a specific LDAP search in C using the OpenLDAP 2.6 C client library. I know that the search only returns a specific set of attributes (namely `mail`, `mailAlias`, and `mailAccount`), because I only query for those attributes. Each of the three attributes might be multi-valued (i.e. appear several times in the result) and encodes an RFC822 mail address (i.e. `someone@some-domain.tld`) as an IA5 string.

All I need is the union set of all values of all attributes as a `char*[]` which then will be further processed by the C program. I do not care which value belongs to which attribute. This means if the result of the search is something like

```
dn: uid=johndoe,ou=users,dc=my-domain,dc=tld
mail: john.doe@somewhere.tld
mail: jdoe@here.tld
mailAccount: john.doe@my-domain.tld
mailAlias: doe@my-domain.tld
```

then I eventually want to have `char* result[] = { "john.doe@somewhere.tld", "jdoe@here.tld", "john.doe@my-domain.tld", "doe@my-domain.tld" }`. The order and duplicates are not important. The C program will deal with that downstream. Note, if the search returns more than one entry, the result shall still be the union set of all values of all attributes of all entries.

Currently, my code looks essentially like this

```c
LDAPMessage* ldap_result_msg = NULL;
int result_code = ldap_search_ext_s( ldap_handle, ..., &ldap_result_msg );
// ... error handling left out ...
struct string_array_t* result = create_string_array(); // a dynamic array very much like std::vector<std::string> in C++
for(
    LDAPMessage* ldap_entry_msg = ldap_first_entry( ldap_handle, ldap_result_msg );
    ldap_entry_msg != NULL;
    ldap_entry_msg = ldap_next_entry( ldap_handle, ldap_entry_msg )
) {
    BerElement* berptr;
    for(
        char* ldap_attr = ldap_first_attribute( ldap_handle, ldap_entry_msg, &berptr );
        ldap_attr != NULL;
        ldap_attr = ldap_next_attribute( ldap_handle, ldap_entry_msg, berptr )
    ) {
        struct berval** values = ldap_get_values_len( ldap_handle, ldap_entry_msg, ldap_attr );
        char* value = NULL;
        for( int i = 0; values[i] != NULL; ++i ) {
            value = malloc( values[i]->bv_len + 1 );
            strncpy( value, values[i]->bv_val, values[i]->bv_len );
            value[ values[i]->bv_len ] = '\0';
            push_onto_string_array( result, value );
            free( value );
        }
        ldap_value_free_len( values );
        ldap_memfree( ldap_attr );
    }
    ber_free( berptr, 0 );
}
ldap_msgfree( ldap_result_msg );
```

I have two concerns, I see two issues which might be improved:

*1. Unnecessary inefficient walk over the LDAP result message*

Currently, I iterate over each entry via `ldap_next_entry`, for each entry over each attribute via `ldap_next_attribute` and then retrieve the values for each specific attribute via `ldap_get_values_len`. If one looks at how `ldap_get_values_len` is implemented at [OpenLDAP.org, LibLDAP, `getvalues.c:59`](https://git.openldap.org/openldap/openldap/-/blob/master/libraries/libldap/getvalues.c?ref_type=heads#L59), then one sees that `getvalues` searches through the result from the beginning to find the provided attribute.  Given the fact that I am only interested in the union of all string values, this appears very inefficient. Is there any way to traverse the result message in a single pass?

*2. Unnecessary allocation/freeing of dynamic memory*

The method `push_onto_string_array( result, value )` makes a deep copy of the provided `value` anyway, i.e. the 2nd argument is a `char * const`. Nonetheless, the loop allocates and frees `berval** values` for each entry and attribute as well as makes another deep copy for each attribute value, adds a `NUL` at the end of the string and then passes this to `push_onto_string_array( result, value )` which makes another copy of its own.

Comment: You are worrying about CPU efficiency of an I/O-bound program.

Comment: Yes, I know that it is a unnecessary optimization, but I don't like obvious inefficiency. It's a matter of personal taste. In particular I am wondering whether I overlooked something in the OpenLDAP docs which would provide a cleaner and more efficient approach.

Comment: It’s not inefficient unless it’s significant.